# MATLAB measure a function run time

Tags: matlab

How to print the time of a function in MATLAB

example:

```
%%%TAKE TIME
A = [2 1 3 ; 1 2 5 ;3 5 4 ]
[U,S,V]            = svd(A)
%%%FINISH TIME
```

whats the syntax?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can also use the nonsingleton forms of [tic and toc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/tic.html):

```
tStart=tic;
A = [2 1 3 ; 1 2 5 ;3 5 4 ]
[U,S,V]            = svd(A)
tElapsed=toc(tStart);
```

This allows the use of more than one timer. (otherwise you have to ensure exclusive use of `tic` and `toc` for one measurement)

Answer (score 12):

```
tic()
A = [2 1 3 ; 1 2 5 ;3 5 4 ]
[U,S,V]            = svd(A)
toc()
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are many functions and assignments in your code you may use `profile` function from matlab library. Before running m file write profile on to command window. After execution check each function's and children function's run time via profile report. You can acquire detailed explanation via `help profile`.